# How to custom filter bugs in MantisBT

Tags: php, mantis

I want to filter my bugs in MantisBT 1.2.14 *only* by a defined custom filter.
I can load the filter from the database by using

```
$t_filter = filter_ensure_valid_filter( filter_get_row($t_filter_id) );
```

Then I try to get the rows by this filter with:

```
$t_rows = filter_get_bug_rows( $f_page_number, $t_per_page, 
                               $t_page_count,$t_bug_count, $t_filter );
```

with all paramaters but `$t_filter` equals `null`. Here it turns out, that always all bugs are loaded.

I tried

```
$t_rows = filter_get_bug_rows( $f_page_number, $t_per_page, $t_page_count, 
                               $t_bug_count, $t_filter, $t_filter['project_id'] );
```

which should set the project to filter on, but with no success.

I Also tried to do it like it is done in the `view_all_bug_page.php` of mantis:

```
$t_rows = filter_get_bug_rows( $f_page_number, $t_per_page, $t_page_count, 
                               $t_bug_count, null, null, null, true );
```

But here (I guess) it is additionally using the *current project* from cache for filtering.

Is it possible to use **only advanced custom filters on bugs** in MantisBT, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was: **one has to use the filter string** from the `$t_filter` array.

```
# get filter string
$t_filter_string = explode('#', $t_filter['filter_string'], 2);

# get bug rows with unserialized filter string
$t_rows = filter_get_bug_rows($f_page_number, $t_per_page, $t_page_count, 
                              $t_bug_count, unserialize($t_filter_string[1]),
                              helper_get_current_project());
```

So the wanted rows are returned and additionally the current project is used to filter.